# Parsing JSON using GET method with Volley in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, get, android-volley

I got this `json` `array`:

```
  {
   "conferences": [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Conferencia Magistral",
    "description": "Conferencia bien chingona lalala",
    "speaker": "Jorge",
    "biography": "bioo",
    "place": {
     "name": "Auditorio",
     "description": "Presentacion de peliculas y documentales"
   },
   "date": "31/10/2015",
   "time": "16:00"
}
]
}
```

And this is my code in **Android Studio**:

```
 queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonArrayRequest JsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            try {

                for (int i = 1, count = response.length(); i < count; i++) {

                    EventInfo eventInfo = new EventInfo();
                    eventInfo.name = response.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                    eventInfo.date =   response.getJSONObject(i).getString("date");
                    eventInfo.hour_event =   response.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");
                    eventInfo.link="http://www.tallertoa.com/v1/files/gimgs/7_botanico-lamina-21.jpg";
                    eventInfo.description = response.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
                    eventInfos.add(eventInfo);


                }
                  recList.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.e("JSON", response.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                showErrorDialog("error Json parser", "error al parsear objeto Json Evento");
                Log.e("json error",e.toString());
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.add(JsonRequest);

}
```

So, i cant parse this Json Array, I've done this but with POST method, so i was wondering if any of you could tell me how to do this using volley

Comment: can you post what and where are you getting the error/exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "conferences": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Conferencia Magistral",
            "description": "Conferencia bien chingona lalala",
            "speaker": "Jorge",
            "biography": "bioo",
            "place": {
                "name": "Auditorio",
                "description": "Presentacion de peliculas y documentales"
            },
            "date": "31/10/2015",
            "time": "16:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Firstly, this is a JSONObject, not a JSONArray. You can go [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) for more information

> JSONObject: ...A string beginning with **{** (left brace) and ending with **}** (right brace).
>
> JSONArray: ...A string that begins with **[** (left bracket) and ends with **]** (right bracket).

As a result, you can use a `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `JsonArrayRequest`

Hope this helps!