# Parse url having single object using http request

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask

My url is:  http://a.nextput.com/apps/init/4/a/9fe2d2cbaa8332a4633be17b79208181-2y-10-ELVM4HwkaYaCVu6203Zjfus-G/o?aff_id={aff_id}

It contains single object `{"success":true}`. How to parse this `url` and store the `json` data in a variable?

my doInBackground method:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

    String json = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        url =  new URL("http://a.nextput.com/apps/init/4/a/9fe2d2cbaa8332a4633be17b79208181-2y-10-ELVM4HwkaYaCVu6203Zjfus-G/o?aff_id=");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        int data = reader.read();

        while (data != -1) {

            char currentChar = (char) data;
            data = reader.read();
            json += currentChar;


        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return json;

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    boolean state = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("state",state);
    editor.commit();
    return null;

}
```

In return json; it is showing incompatible types and in JSONObject it is showing unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException. How to resolve it?

Comment: there are lots of example avilable of json parsing...plz try first them..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON using GET method with Volley in Adnroid Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959137/parsing-json-using-get-method-with-volley-in-adnroid-studio)

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Its not the duplicate of the question you have suggested. I have tried json parsing. But here it is only one object and that too is response. I'm confused how to perform parsing in this url. Please help.

Comment: what have you tried @himanshutiwari ...?? It simple use like that JsonObject jsonobject = new JsonObject("here is yours response"); and than String sucess= jsonobject.getBoolean("success");

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I have edited the question and showing what I have tried. Its giving some errors. I also mentioned them in the last. Please help me to resolve them.

Comment: @himashu.tiwari.. now i am able to undersatnd your problem..please be specific before ansking question here..provide full code with problem here than we will able to solve as possiblee...for your editing +1 ..please check my solution related to connectionurl is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33749770/3946958

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution of this -

```
 // Making HTTP request
       InputStream is = null;
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);//YOUR URL

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
        JSONObject  jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        boolean isSuccess = jObj.getBoolean("success");
        System.out.println("success : " + isSuccess);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: In your code it is showing cannot resolve symbol "is"

Comment: InputStream is = null;